# Cannot get AutomationPattern from white object

Tags: c#, .net, ui-automation, white-framework

I'm having a problem, because I need to get a piece information about `AutomationPatterns` of Text in Windows Calculator, but `GetAutomationPatterns()` returns an empty array.

I'm trying to access that in this way:

```
AutomationElement aeItem = uiitem.AutomationElement;

foreach (AutomationPattern prop in aeItem.GetSupportedPatterns())
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(prop.ProgrammaticName);
```

How to achieve my goal, cause I need to get a value of that text box and without a pattern it seems to be impossible...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `AutomationElement` you're looking at is indeed a `TextBox`? `TextBlock`, for example, exposes no `AutomationPattern` whatsoever, and you'll have to use its `Name` property to get its content.